# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, error-handling, typeerror

I have a the following code:

```
def fib(n): 
    if n < 1: return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Where  I would put in an array from 1-10000 as n and it would give me an error. May someone help me point out the problem?

Comment: the problem is exactly what it says it is :) trying to substract/compare an array to an integer doesn't make much sense.

Comment: for reference, the Fibonacci function is usually defined as taking an integer n, and returning another integer. Why do you think it should take a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the problem is that you can't pass a list to your function. Your function wants an integer value.

```
>>> fib(5)
13
```

As expected. So you should pass just a number (n) to your function to calculate fibonacci of it.